# Autocomplete: Formatting the results

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-autocomplete

Let me try ask this again with a code snippet with what I have tried

I'm trying to format a Jquery autocomplete to include a heading for each of the data sources and to highlight the term. I'm using Codeigniter and thought maybe the easiest would be to format it before i send it back:

**JS:**

```
$( ".auto-search" ).autocomplete({
        source: '/json/autocomplete_search',
        minLength: 2,

    });
```

**PHP (Codeigniter)**

```
public function autocomplete_search()
{
    $term = $this->input->get('term');

    //load model and get results
    $this->load->model("mymodel");
    $results1= $this->mymodel->search_one($term);
    $results2= $this->mymodel->search_two($term);

    //Start JSON string
    $json='[';

    //first source
    if ($result1->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $json .= '{"value":"<h3>Heading One<h3>"}';
        foreach ($results1->result_array() as $r1)
        {
            $result = str_replace($term,"<strong>".$term."</strong>",$r1['title']);
            $json .= ',{"value":"'.$result.'"}';
        }
    }

    //second source
    if ($result2->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        if ($result1->num_rows() > 0){$json .=  ',';}
        $json .= '{"value":"<h3>Heading Two<h3>"}';

        foreach ($results2->result_array() as $r2)
        {
            $result = str_replace($term,"<strong>".$term."</strong>",$r2['location']);
            $json .= ',{"value":"'.$result.'"}';
        }
    }

    //Close JSON string
    $json .= ']';
    echo  $json;
}`
```

Unfortunately I'm not getting a formatted output, instead, it actually adds the words < h1> and < strong> to the output. Here is sample output:

[image]

Comment: It's a json? Did you try parse it and output the value at any point?

Comment: I didnt think I had to parse it as I am getting an output like the one in the image. To be honest, not sure where I'd parse it as I'm creating the json string manually. That JavaScript snippet is the only JavaScript that I am using and it calls that php function which returns the echo and populates the autocomplete.

Comment: Can you link the js file you're using for this function?  After sorting through the source, I -may- have a solution.  Don't get your hopes up here, just trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I've found a way to do it. Here is how I did it:

**Javascript:**

```
    $( ".auto-search" ).autocomplete({
        source: '/hotpepper/json/autocomplete_search2',
        minLength: 2,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $(".ui-autocomplete .ui-menu-item a").each(function (i) {
                var row = $(this).html();
                row=row.replace(/&lt;/g,"<");
                row=row.replace(/&gt;/g,">");
                $(this).html(row);
              });   
        },

    });
```

PHP(Codeigniter):

```
public function autocomplete_search2()
{
    $term = $this->input->get('term');

    //load model and get results
    $this->load->model("establishment_model");
    $results1= $this->establishment_model->search_autocomplete_est($term);
    $results2= $this->establishment_model->search_autocomplete_loc($term);

    //Start JSON string
    $json='[';

    //first source
    if ($results1->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        $header= "<h3 style='font-weight:bold'>Accommodation:</h3>";
        $json .= '{"value":"'.$header.'"}';
        foreach ($results1->result_array() as $r1)
        {
            $result = str_replace($term,"<strong style='color:#C00'>".$term."</strong>",$r1['establishment_name']);
            $json .= ',{"value":"'.$result.'"}'; 
        }
    }

    //second source
    if ($results2->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        if ($results1->num_rows() > 0){$json .=  ',';}
        $header= "<h3 style='font-weight:bold'>Destinations:</h3>";
        $json .= '{"value":"'.$header.'"}';

        foreach ($results2->result_array() as $r2)
        {
            $result = str_replace($term,"<strong style='color:#C00'>".$term."</strong>",$r2['establishment_location']);
            $json .= ',{"value":"'.$result.'"}';
        }
    }

    //Close JSON string
    $json .= ']';
    echo  $json;
}
```

Since auto-complete escapes my html that I send through, I just unescape it by replacing `&lt;` and `&gt;` with <> when i open the auto complete box.

EDIT:
Also had to add the following event to format the result back:

```
close: function(event, ui) {
                var result = $(this).val();
                if (result.search("</h3>") ==-1)
                {
                    result=result.replace(/<strong style='color:#C00'>/g,"");
                    result=result.replace(/<\/strong>/g,"");
                }
            else
            {
                result="";
            }
            $(this).val(result);
        }
```

Comment: Well, your solution is better, as mine had you editing the source file.  Don't forget to accept your answer.